# Spring throws AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException when trying to access secured paths

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm trying to convert my spring xml configuration to a java type configuration. So far I have gotten most things working but I am struggling with configuring the security of the application. I currently get the following error when trying to access a secured path.

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

I assume I have missed something important but I don't understand what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Here are my configuration files.

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


  @Autowired
  private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private NegotiateSecurityFilter securityFilter;

  @Bean
  public WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffleAuthProvider(){
    return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
  }

  @Bean(name="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider")
  @Autowired
  public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(
      final WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider
  ){
    NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider bean = new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    List<String> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
    protocols.add("Negotiate");
    bean.setProtocols(protocols);
    return bean;
  }
  @Bean
  public BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffleAuthProvider){
    return new BasicSecurityFilterProvider(waffleAuthProvider);
  }

  @Bean(name="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection")
  @Autowired
  public waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(
      final BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider,
      final NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider
  ) {
    final List<SecurityFilterProvider> lsp = new ArrayList<>();
    lsp.add(negotiateSecurityFilterProvider);
    lsp.add(basicSecurityFilterProvider);
    return new waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection(lsp.toArray(new SecurityFilterProvider[]{}));
  }

  @Bean(name="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint")
  @Autowired
  public waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
    final waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint ep = new waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
    ep.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return ep;
  }

  @Bean(name="negotiateSecurityFilter")
  @Autowired
  public waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(
      final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection
  ){
    waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter bean = new waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter();
    bean.setRoleFormat("both");
    bean.setPrincipalFormat("fqn");
    bean.setAllowGuestLogin(false);
    bean.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/img/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/partials/**");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // A user needs to have the role user and has to be authenticated
    Filter customNegotiateSecurityFilter = new CustomPreAuthSecurityFilter();
    Filter customPreAuthSecurityFilter = new CustomNegotiateSecurityFilter();
    http
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .addFilterBefore(customPreAuthSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(customNegotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

SpringConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.realitylabs.spa"})
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:app.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:general.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:log4j.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:setup/app.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:setup/wro.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:setup/jdbc.properties"),
    @PropertySource("file:${CONFIG_DIR}/config.properties")
})
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  Environment env;

  @Autowired
  SpringPostConstructHook sp;

  private static final int CACHE_PERIOD = 31556926; // one year

  // Configure static routes
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry reg){
    reg.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/assets/img/")
        .setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD);

    reg.addResourceHandler("/assets/" + env.getProperty("VERSION") + "/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/assets/")
        .setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD);
  }

  // Configuration variables
  long MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 5000000;

  // WRO4J config (js and css merge and minification)
  @Bean
  public PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    Resource wroResource = new ClassPathResource("wro.properties");
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(wroResource);
    return propertiesFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean(name = "wroFilter")
  public ConfigurableWroFilter getConfigurableWroFilter() throws IOException {
    ConfigurableWroFilter filter = new ConfigurableWroFilter();
    filter.setProperties(propertiesFactoryBean().getObject());
    return filter;
  }

  // Post construction print outs
  @Bean
  public SpringPostConstructHook postConstructHook(){
    return new SpringPostConstructHook();
  }

  // JSP view rendering
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    bean.setOrder(1);
    return bean;
  }

  // Handle file uploads
  @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver bean =  new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    bean.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
    return bean;
  }

  // Set specific hibernate config for postgres.
  @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper om = new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(om);
    return jsonConverter;
  }

  // Poolable connection.
  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc_driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc_databaseurl"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc_username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc_password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public  DataSourceConnectionFactory getDataSourceConnectionFactory() {
    DataSourceConnectionFactory bean = new DataSourceConnectionFactory(getDataSource());
    return bean;
  }

  @Bean
  public GenericObjectPool getPool() {
    GenericObjectPool bean = new GenericObjectPool();
    bean.setMaxIdle(30000);
    bean.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
    return bean;
  }

  @Bean(name = "poolableConnectionFactory")
  public PoolableConnectionFactory getPoolableConnectionFactory() {
    PoolableConnectionFactory bean = new PoolableConnectionFactory(getDataSourceConnectionFactory(),getPool(),null,null,false,true);
    return bean;
  }

  @Bean(name = "pooledDS")
  @DependsOn({"poolableConnectionFactory"})
  public PoolingDataSource getPoolingDataSource() {
    PoolingDataSource bean = new PoolingDataSource(getPool());
    return bean;
  }

  // Configure flyway database migrations
  @Bean(name = "flyWay")
  public Flyway getFlyWay(){
    Flyway bean = new Flyway();
    bean.setDataSource(getPoolingDataSource());
    bean.setLocations("classpath:db/migrations");
    bean.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
    bean.migrate();
    return bean;
  }

  // Configure hibernate ORM
  @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
  @DependsOn({"flyWay"})
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
    LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(getPoolingDataSource());
    bean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.realitylabs.spa.entity");
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("jdbc_dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.showSQL"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "30");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "30");
    bean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    bean.setDataSource(getPoolingDataSource());
    return bean;
  }


  // Configure scheduled jobs
  @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
  }

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 3 * * ?")
  public void runSGCSJob() {
    SGCSJob job = new SGCSJob();
    try {
      job.updateEmployees();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 2 * * ?")
  public void runLimeJob() {
    LimeJob job = new LimeJob();
    try {
      job.updateCourses();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // Print config and start jobs post construction
  @PostConstruct
  @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
  public void init() throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    sp.printConfiguration();
    sp.runJobs();
  }

}
```

CacheConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration implements CachingConfigurer {
  // Replace the cache manager with ehcache
  @Bean
  @Override
  public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(getEhCacheFactory().getObject());
  }

  @Override
  public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
    return new SimpleCacheResolver();
  }

  @Override
  public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
    return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
  }

  @Override
  public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
  }

  // Configure ehcache
  private EhCacheManagerFactoryBean getEhCacheFactory(){
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    factoryBean.setShared(true);
    return factoryBean;
  }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="MyCareerID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>RDS</display-name>

  <!-- Configure the session -->
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>45</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>

  <!-- Annotation config -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Context config location -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.realitylabs.spa.springConfig.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Force UTF-8 encoding-->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Expose the security filter for the tests -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <!-- WRO4J configuration -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>wroFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <!-- Mapping wro for delivery of combined js files -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/assets/wro/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Escape html sent to the server -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- The container running spring -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Mapping root route to spring -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Mapping error pages -->
  <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

I'm not certain if any other files might be interesting please ask if you need anything else.